# How to initialize buttons in jquery ui dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui dialog. I have initialized a dialog at `document.ready` event.

```
   $("#globalConfirm").dialog({
        width: 500, autoOpen: false, resizable: false, draggable: false,
        modal: false        
   });
```

This dialog is for confirmation. Now later i want to add a buttons options and there callback functions like :

```
   $("#globalConfirm").dialog("option", "buttons", '{
        "Confirm": function (event, ui) {
            //jquery code
        },
        "Cancle": function (event, ui) {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }'
    );
```

Is this write way to initialize the buttons option of jquery ui dialog after initializing dialog ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just pass the option as an object, not a string.

```
   $("#globalConfirm").dialog("option", "buttons", {
        "Confirm": function (event, ui) {
            //jQuery code
        },
        "Cancel": function (event, ui) {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    );
```